# .htaccess file causing too many redirects error

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have the following redirect rules in my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule !^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

This is causing a too many redirects error on my site. Moreover, this problem is occurring only on my local machine and the site is working just fine on the remote server.

Please help!

Comment: What are trying to achieve?

Comment: I have my website programmed in codeigniter. This is the .htaccess file for the website which I copied from codeigniter's user guide. When I open my website, there is this redirect error in the console.

Comment: Something is missing here. The `$1` backreference seems out of place in that context. Use the pattern at https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html?highlight=htaccess with `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` compared as `!-f, !-d`.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski  I tried removing the rule containing the $1 backreference but the error is still there.

Comment: the `!^(.*)$` seems never matches as it is "negative all"

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule !^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Try adding the question mark after index.php and check Michael Berkowski's answer.

Comment: I tried doing it your way, but still I see the error.

Comment: Is mod_rewrite enabled? Does it work without the htaccess file? try removing the slash before index.php.

Answer (score 0):

Just follow following steps:

1. Go to application/config/config.php and Change `$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';` to `$config['index_page'] = ''; // remove index.php`
2. Add base url in same file application/config/config.php as: `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/yourapp';`
3. Check your apache server has Rewrite module enabled.
4. add .htaccess file in your root directory

   `RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]`